# If statements return "nan" and "inf" in label field not sure why?

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement

So i have an intricate system of if statements all which after evaluating a certain statement, the correct if statement 'activates' and prints something to the label on my view controller.  But no matter what data i enter and activate the different if statements all the label prints is either "nan" or "inf" and im not sure why or what is causing this?

code:

```
if (CurrentPH < 7.2 && CurrentPH >= 6.2) {
    float desiredChangePh = 1;
    float changeFactorPH = desiredChangePh / CurrentPhPPM;
    float chemicalDosagePh = PoolFactorPh * changeFactorPH * CurrentPhPounds;
    self.PhChemicalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", chemicalDosagePh];
    self.PhUpOrDownLabel.text = @"Ph Increaser";
}

else if (CurrentPH > 7.3 && CurrentPH <= 8.3) {
    float DesiredChangePhDecreaser = 1;
    float ChangeFactorPhDecreaser = DesiredChangePhDecreaser / CurrentPhDecreaserPPM;
    float ChemicalDosagePhDecreaser = PoolFactorPhDecreaser * ChangeFactorPhDecreaser *              CurrentPhDecreaserLbs;
    self.PhChemicalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",   ChemicalDosagePhDecreaser];
    self.PhUpOrDownLabel.text = @"Ph Decreaser";
}
else if (CurrentPH < 6.2 && CurrentPH >= 5.2){
    float DesiredChangeLowPh = 1;
    float ChangeFactorLowPh = DesiredChangeLowPh / CurrentPhPPM;
    float ChemicalDosageLowPh = PoolFactorPh * ChangeFactorLowPh * CurrentPhPounds;
    self.PhChemicalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", ChemicalDosageLowPh];
    self.PhUpOrDownLabel.text = @"Ph Increaser";
}
else if (CurrentPH > 8.3 && CurrentPH <= 9.3){
    float DesiredChangHighPH = 1;
    float ChangeFactorHighPh = DesiredChangHighPH / CurrentPhDecreaserPPM;
    float ChemicalDosageHighPH = PoolFactorPhDecreaser * ChangeFactorHighPh *  CurrentPhDecreaserLbs;
    self.PhChemicalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",ChemicalDosageHighPH];
    self.PhUpOrDownLabel.text = @"Ph Decreaser";

}
else if (CurrentPH > 9.3){
    UIAlertView *OpenALertPhHigh = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pool Pal"   message:@"Your Ph seems unusually high, check to make sure you entered it correctly or consult the Pool Tips page for further instruction" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [OpenALertPhHigh show];
}
else if (CurrentPH < 5.2) {
    UIAlertView *OpenALertPhLow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pool Pal" message:@"Your Ph seems unusually low, check to make sure you entered it correctly or consult the Pool Tips page for further instruction" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [OpenALertPhLow show];
}
else{
    self.PhChemicalLabel.text = @"Your Ph is perfect";
    NSLog(@"okay");
}
```

}

Comment: First of all, you've got the if..else syntax incorrect.  You don't have an opening { after each instance of `else` (except the last one).  And you should have all the matching closing }'s at the end.

Comment: What are you talking about @GlennRay? The syntax and the brackets are fine...

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of the `if...else` syntax, not the `if...else if` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're making some kind of math error, such as division by zero or an operation involving a nil object. Make sure `CurrentPhPPM` and other similar variables used in calculating the `labels` are initialized properly. Can't provide any other help without knowing more about how those variables are initialized.